# My timestamp strings have "-05:00" at the end, what does it mean and how do I handle it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

My csv file has a different format TIMESTAMP. Screenshot of the file is given below:

```
2015-01-01 00:00:00-05:00
2015-01-01 00:01:00-05:00
2015-01-01 00:02:00-05:00
2015-01-01 00:03:00-05:00
2015-01-01 00:04:00-05:00
2015-01-01 00:05:00-05:00
2015-01-01 00:06:00-05:00
```

My code is given below:

```
colnames = ['RefCell1_Wm2_Avg', 'AmbTemp_C_Avg', 'InvPDC_kW_Avg', 'InvVDVoltage_V_Avg', 'InvPAC_kW_Avg'] # extract these columns only
raw_df = pd.read_csv('example.csv',names = colnames)
```

This gives a weird index as given below. The first two indexes are only shown below:

```
raw_df.index=
('2015-01-01 00:00:00-05:00', '-4.43309582861912', '-8.782201339719725', '-4.5425994383962', '173899.0', '-3.4700000286102295', '0.0', '-0.5479999780654907', '-0.03999999910593033', '-2.2290000915527344', '11.75', '277.3999938964844', '276.5', '278.1000061035156', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '20.90999984741211', '0.0', '60.13999938964844', '0.0', '758073.0', '13.229999542236328', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '16.0', '-2.9260001182556152', '-8.420000076293945', '-0.03799999877810478', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '60.0', '59.900001525878906', '62.900001525878906', '0.0', '274.0', '274.0', '276.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '350.0', '721347.0', '28359.0', '65230.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '-0.0010000000474974513', '0.0', '0.0010000000474974513', '0.009999999776482582', '0.004999999888241291', '0.006000000052154064', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '8383.0', '11754.0', '11696.0', '11898.0', '10092.0', '10063.0', '8216.0', '1.0870000123977661', '255.6999969482422', '11.350000381469727', '1.7000000476837158', '3.5339999198913574', '3.0', '-1.0', '13.989999771118164', '0.0020000000949949026', '0.5889999866485596', '3.0', '2.0', '0.0', '0.0', '-8.619999885559082', '-8.289999961853027', '-8.680000305175781', '-8.479999542236328', '-8.3100004196167')
('2015-01-01 00:01:00-05:00', '-4.43309582861912', '-8.782201339719725', '-4.5425994383962', '173900.0', '-3.4760000705718994', '0.0', '-0.5479999780654907', '-0.03999999910593033', '-2.0989999771118164', '11.6899995803833', '277.3999938964844', '276.5', '278.20001220703125', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '20.950000762939453', '0.0', '60.130001068115234', '0.0', '758073.0', '13.210000038146973', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '16.0', '-2.88100004196167', '-8.510000228881836', '-0.03799999877810478', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '60.0', '59.900001525878906', '62.900001525878906', '0.0', '274.0', '274.0', '276.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '350.0', '721347.0', '28359.0', '65230.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '-0.0010000000474974513', '0.0010000000474974513', '0.0020000000949949026', '0.009999999776482582', '0.004999999888241291', '0.004999999888241291', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '8383.0', '11754.0', '11696.0', '11898.0', '10092.0', '10063.0', '8216.0', '0.7929999828338623', '265.79998779296875', '13.1899995803833', '1.7000000476837158', '3.5339999198913574', '3.0', '-1.0', '13.989999771118164', '0.0020000000949949026', '0.5889999866485596', '3.0', '2.0', '0.0', '0.0', '-8.609999656677246', '-8.350000381469727', '-8.520000457763672', '-8.180000305175781', '-8.020000457763672')
```

But I want the index to beimport it as:

```
raw_df.index = 
2015-01-01 00:00:00
2015-01-01 00:01:00
2015-01-01 00:02:00
2015-01-01 00:03:00
2015-01-01 00:04:00
2015-01-01 00:05:00
2015-01-01 00:06:00
```

[image]

When import the csv file, the index looks weird as given below

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add your `read_csv` code.

Comment: @cs95 Now I have included the code and modified the question. Please, have a look.

Comment: I think you should use `pd.read_csv('example.csv',usecols=['TIMESTAMP', *colnames], parse_dates=['TIMESTAMP'])`. See what that does.

Comment: @cs95 Yes! your code did work to an extent. I have modified my above question with latest solution obtained after your code. Now I have a separate column `TIMESTAMP` but it is not in datetime format and I want to set this as index. Presently it looks like `2015-01-01 00:00:00-05:00` but I want it to be like `2015-01-01 00:00:00`

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea. Your datetimes are _timezone aware_. You usually want to retain that information than remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your datetimes are timezone aware (the "-05:00" indicates you are 5 hours behind UTC, for example). What you'd want to do is load your TIMESTAMP column, then use `tz_localize` to convert it to a naive timestamp (no timezone information).

```
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv', usecols=['TIMESTAMP', *colnames], index_col=[0])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, errors='coerce').tz_localize(None)
```

OTOH, I don't recommend this because it destroys information about your dates. A better option would be

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).tz_convert('utc').tz_localize(None)
```

Comment: Oho....I did not know that it is actually timezone information. Thanks for this valuable information. Previously I thought it a some wrong.

Comment: Where this timezone information will not disturb the actual datetime ?

Comment: @Msquare I don't understand your question, sorry. The reason I advise you to keep this information is because it might make a difference to your results when you're analysing the data.

Comment: Please, ignore my question. I was only wondering that this timezone information will not hamper any datetime operation I do on it.